# Duplicate indexing in Rails Database Using PSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, activerecord, indexing

In my Rails project I want to speed up database queries by giving them proper indexing.

I have a `Message` model with columns `created_at`, `status_updated_at`, `message_type`, `direction`, `status`, among others.

In some places I need to run a query like Query 1:

```
Message.where(created_at: @start_date..@end_date)
                      .where(message_type: @message_types)
                      .where(direction: 'outgoing')
                      .where(status: Message::STATUS_DELIVERED)
                      .where('status_updated_at - created_at >= ?', "90 seconds")
                      .where('status_updated_at - created_at < ?', "180 seconds")
```

In some other places I only need to query by only 1 of the columns, for example, simply `Message.where(direction: 'outgoing')` (call this Query 2).

For the long query, Query 1, I created this migration in order to speed it up:

```
    add_index :messages, [:direction, :status, :created_at, :status_updated_at], name: 'dashboard_delivery_time_index'
```

For the second query, Query 2, in addition to the indexing added above, I created this migration:

```
add_index :messages, :direction, name: 'index_messages_on_direction'
```

Will the second migration be redundant and unnecessary because the first migration already includes `:direction`?

The code is running fine. But just wondering if the second migration is necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since direction is the first column in the first index, you probably do not need an additional index on direction.  If it were not the first column, you would need it.  That's not to say that postgres wouldn't use it and it might even help a little because the index will be smaller than the first one, but the gains should be slight.

Is postgres using status_updated_at and created_at from your index?  I would be somewhat surprised if it is.  It may be better to index direction, status, and status_updated_at - created_at.